# WooCommerce: How to insert a value from $_GET into $order->update_meta_data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, get, hook-woocommerce

I'm trying to insert a value as custom meta for a WooCommerce order from a query string parameter the url e.g.: **mystore.com/checkout?myparam=customvalue**

For some reason I cannot return any value from `$_GET` :

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'before_checkout_create_order', 20, 2);

 function before_checkout_create_order( $order, $data ) {

    if ( isset( $_GET['myparam'] ) ) {
        $myvalue = $_GET['myparam'];
    }

    $order->update_meta_data( '_mymeta', $myvalue );

 }
```

I'm confused because I believe `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` fires upon hitting submit for the checkout so I don't understand why it wouldn't be able to pull this from the current url.

I've tested dummy values such as `$myvalue = 'test';` to ensure the meta data is inserted and that works fine.

Comment: No errors. I replaced the clause with your suggestion, and now the checkout does not continue to finalize payment. Not seeing any checkout validation errors.

Comment: I'm not able to pickup `query variables` from the url when `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` fires. Do you have to pass your data through a `query_var`?  Maybe you could set a custom `global variable` for your data.

Comment: _"I believe woocommerce_checkout_create_order fires upon hitting submit for the checkout so I don't understand why it wouldn't be able to pull this from the current url."_ - and does the "current URL" actually contain that parameter? This would of course not be the URL that you used to request the checkout page, but the URL specified in the `action` attribute of the form that you are submitting from there.

Answer (score 3):

Like i said in the comments, i'm not able to pickup any `query variables` from the url when `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` fires. However, i can think of a workaround for this:

1. When the checkout page loads with your `custom query variable` up in the url, we create a hidden field on the page and store the value of your `custom query variable` as the value of that hidden field.
2. Then when `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` fires, we update the order meta data.
3. And finally we use `woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address` hook to dispaly that value on the admin order screen.

---

> **Feel free to customize the following codes as you see fit**

1-Adding your hidden field and populating its value with your url custom query variable.

> mystore.com/checkout?myparam=customvalue

```php
add_action('woocommerce_after_checkout_billing_form', 'your_custom_checkout_hidden_field');

function your_custom_checkout_hidden_field($checkout)
{

  if (isset($_GET['myparam'])) {
    $myvalue = sanitize_text_field($_GET['myparam']);
  }

  echo '<div id="your_custom_checkout_hidden_field">
            <input type="hidden" class="input-hidden" name="myparam" id="myparam" value="' . $myvalue . '">
    </div>';
}
```

2- Receiving the value of your hidden field when `woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta` fires and updating the order mata data.

```php
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta', 'save_your_custom_checkout_hidden_field');

function save_your_custom_checkout_hidden_field($order_id)
{
  if (!empty($_POST['myparam'])) {
    update_post_meta($order_id, '_mymeta', sanitize_text_field($_POST['myparam']));
  }
}
```

3- Displaying that meta data value on the admin order screen.

```php
add_action('woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'your_custom_checkout_hidden_field_display_admin_order_meta', 10, 1);

function your_custom_checkout_hidden_field_display_admin_order_meta($order)
{
  $my_value = get_post_meta($order->get_id(), '_mymeta', true);
  echo $my_value;
}
```

---

If you also want to show that value to your customer on the order details screen, then you can use the following code:

```php
add_action('woocommerce_order_details_after_customer_details', 'show_your_custom_value_to_customer', 10);

function show_your_custom_value_to_customer($order)
{
  echo '<p>' . 'Your meta data: ' . get_post_meta($order->get_id(), '_mymeta', true) . '</p>';
}
```

Let me know if this works for you!